# Add fonts to image using Jib

Tags: docker, maven, jib, maven-jib

We have Jib in out project instead of Docker containerization and now I have a task to add fonts to final image.

Commands that I need to reproduce with Jib and how it looks like with Docker:

```
RUN apk --no-cache add curl ttf-dejavu msttcorefonts-installer fontconfig \
  && update-ms-fonts \
  && fc-cache -f
```

Actually I don't think that I need to add all fonts, I need only Times New Roman.

Also I would mention that I don't have any opportunity to change base image, so I can't add fonts to image before Jib using it.

Considering all points, what would you recommend eventually?

Comment: You can’t. Create your own new base image outside of your current build and use that with jib.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen
Is it possible to put fonts as binaries and use extraDirectories?

Comment: Yes.  This doesn’t register them though.  Are you sure this is thought through?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen
No, I am not sure. Just trying to create a working around solution
You think that its not possible to manage this task with Jib ?

Comment: You cannot do the equivalent of `RUN`.  You can put the file in but this looks like you are using an image for something else than it was intended for. Why can’t you make your own base image?